# jQuery animate positions not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, jquery-animate, css-position, slideshow

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/u6M2d/)

For this project I am trying to create a slideshow effect using jQuery's `animate()` method. It works perfectly on all browsers (IE8+) except for Safari (I tested using v7.0). I researched extensively what may be causing this issue, including articles and threads on this site, MDN, and others - none of my searches led to solutions to this particular issue. Some examples of solutions I tried that did not work include: setting the animated elements to `float:left`; not animating to a `position` value of 0 (I tried `1px` but it made no difference); and others.

I'm really stumped by this, and unfortunately I am tied into using jQuery/JS for this project. I cannot rely on CSS3 animations as I have to support some legacy browsers.

Please ignore any lack of optimization in the code - I stripped this down from a larger project and may have left some additional parameters in there that aren't 100% necessary for the purposes of this demonstration.

Finally, I intend on making these slides loop indefinitely when I finalize this project. I doubt that will impact the fixes necessary to get this working in Safari, but it may be worth mentioning so I mentioned it :)

/edit/ - It was easy enough to make the slides loop indefinitely, so I did that :)

HTML:

```
<div id="banner">
    <div id="holder">
        <div id="lookbook-container">
            <div width="607px" height="300px" id="lookbook-item-1" class="lookbook-item"></div>
        </div>
        <img width="100%" height="100%" id="arrow-left" src="http://images.harmonyremote.com/EasyZapper/Support/FAQ/HarmonyOne/25672_ARROWLEFT.png" />
        <img width="100%" height="100%" id="arrow-right" src="http://images.harmonyremote.com/EasyZapper/Support/FAQ/HarmonyOne/25672_arrowright.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
    var itemCount = 1;
    var newLookbookItem = '';

    function setArrowEventListeners() {
        $('#holder').on('click', '#arrow-left', function (e) {
            lookbookLeftClick();
        });

        $('#holder').on('click', '#arrow-right', function (e) {
            lookbookRightClick();
        });
    }

    function unsetArrowEventListeners() {
        $('#holder').off('click', '#arrow-left');
        $('#holder').off('click', '#arrow-right');
    }

    function lookbookLeftClick() {
        switch (itemCount) {
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                newLookbookItem = '<div width="607px" height="300px" id="lookbook-item-1" class="insertedLeft"></div>';
                $('.lookbook-item').before(newLookbookItem);
                cmn_slideLeft(itemCount);
                itemCount = 1;
                break;
            case 3:
                newLookbookItem = '<div width="607px" height="300px" id="lookbook-item-2" class="insertedLeft"></div>';
                $('.lookbook-item').before(newLookbookItem);
                cmn_slideLeft(itemCount);
                itemCount = 2;
                break;
            case 4:
                newLookbookItem = '<div width="607px" height="300px" id="lookbook-item-3" class="insertedLeft"></div>';
                $('.lookbook-item').before(newLookbookItem);
                cmn_slideLeft(itemCount);
                itemCount = 3;
                break;
        }
    }

    function cmn_slideLeft(itemCount) {
        unsetArrowEventListeners();
        $('.insertedLeft').animate({
            'right': 0
        }, 800);

        $('.insertedLeft').addClass('lookbook-item');

        setTimeout(function (e) {
            $('.insertedLeft').removeClass('insertedLeft');
            $('#lookbook-item-' + itemCount).remove();
            setArrowEventListeners();
        }, 800);
    }

    function lookbookRightClick() {
        switch (itemCount) {
            case 1:
                newLookbookItem = '<div width="607px" height="300px" id="lookbook-item-2" class="insertedRight"></div>';
                $('.lookbook-item').after(newLookbookItem);
                cmn_slideRight(itemCount);
                itemCount = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                newLookbookItem = '<div width="607px" height="300px" id="lookbook-item-3" class="insertedRight"></div>';
                $('.lookbook-item').after(newLookbookItem);
                cmn_slideRight(itemCount);
                itemCount = 3;
                break;
            case 3:
                newLookbookItem = '<div width="607px" height="300px" id="lookbook-item-4" class="insertedRight"></div>';
                $('.lookbook-item').after(newLookbookItem);
                cmn_slideRight(itemCount);
                itemCount = 4;
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
        }
    }

    function cmn_slideRight(itemCount) {
        unsetArrowEventListeners();
        $('.insertedRight').animate({
            'right': 0
        }, 800);
        $('.insertedRight').addClass('lookbook-item');
        setTimeout(function (e) {
            $('.insertedRight').removeClass('insertedRight');
            $('#lookbook-item-' + itemCount).remove();
            setArrowEventListeners();
        }, 800);
    }

setArrowEventListeners();
```

Comment: I'm afraid no progress has been made on this on my part. I'm really stumped by the issue - especially because of my novice level of mobile development - any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would think this would be a well known problem, seeing as how it's a very common animation and Safari is a relatively popular browser. Is this something that I alone am experiencing? Can anyone replicate the issue, or point to some area of my code that breaks this animation in Safari?